# Are there any mods that unlock higher level equipment or skill trees?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

In the origin Dawn Of War 2, the level cap is only 20, and the skill tree for each character is much less than Chaos Rising. The only better part was that you can play missions infinite times, something you couldn't do in Chaos Rising. So my question is, are there any mods for the Dawn of War 2 campaign that can unlock higher level equipment or skill trees?

Comment: Don't know about mods for the campaign, but there is some pretty decent DLC available for The Last Stand and multiplayer game modes.

Comment: Hey, Ave Maleficum, I've voted to close your question because it very subjective; using "awesome" means you're looking for opinions, and each person will think different things are awesome.  That means this question is not something we can properly answer.

Comment: Perfect!  That's now an answerable question!

Comment: Voting to reopen as per: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and

Comment: @pleinolijf I know your comment is 11 years old, but I just wanted to add that these multiplayers DLCs are for Dawn of War II: Retribution, which isn't the same game as Dawn of War II (it's a standalone DLC which re-uses the engine and storyline of the original game).